# Why recorded avi speeds up?

Tags: video, editing

I recently recorded an `avi` using VirtualDub with Microsoft's LifeCam Studio 1080p HD. However, when playing back the video and audio keep accelerating as the video progresses.

When I tried to edit the frame rate in MAGIX Movie Edit Pro 17 Plus, the audio track seems fine, but the video track is accelerated.

Any ideas what could have caused this or how I can go about fixing this?

Comment: 1. How to you record with VirtualDub? Do you capture the screen? 2. Do you have the same strange effects when operating in a lower camera resolution?

Comment: @Fred42vid [This is the tutorial](http://xtrm.cc/post/2011/04/10/How-to-capture-1080p-video-from-Microsoft-Lifecam-Studio.aspx) I used to record.

Answer (score 1):

According to the symptoms it seems that the workload is too much for VirtualDub. That does depend on the CPU, but also on the hard disk. Sometimes VirtualDub has to drop frames and resync between video and audio. But in the file header there are only static values that MAGIX and other video editors expect to be constant throughout the video.

You should try setting a smaller frame size and a lower frame rate in **Video->Capture pin**. And in **Capture->Timing** there are some other important options. Try the "Sync video to audio..." alternative under **Resync mode**, or the "Automatically disable resync..." option.

When you find a combination that works, then you can increase the frame size again. I hope this helps.

[image: Capture timing options dialog]

Comment: That was very informative. However, I find myself trying to sync the video/audio for an already recorded video.